# Create or reuse existing Emacs GUI frame

Tags: emacs

Assuming an Emacs server is running, I want `emacsclient <file>` to either create a new frame (like `-c`) when there is no existing frame or reuse an existing frame when there is one. In other words, I want the `-c` only when there is no existing frame. Is that possible?

Comment: Isn't that what leaving out `-c` does anyway? Meaning a simple `emacsclient yourfile.ext` should open in an existing frame if there is one, and if there isn't then it should create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with a set of shell scripts.

my_emacs

```
#!/bin/sh
emacs24-x $@ 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null &
```

You may need to change emacs24-x to something that points to your X11 emacs.

my_emacsclient

```
#!/bin/sh
emacsclient $@ 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null || my_emacs
```

Add both files to you PATH via ~/bin or the like.

In my .emacs I also added the followings lines

```
(load "server")
(unless (server-running-p) (server-start))
```

Also change some environment variables and optionally add an alias

```
export ALTERNATE_EDITOR="my_emacs"
export EDITOR="my_emacsclient -n"
export SUDO_EDITOR="my_emacsclient"
...
alias e="$EDITOR"
```

When you run `e` in your shell it should create or resuse an existing GUI frame. Also, running `e <filename>` opens that file in a frame; you can also pass other flags like `-n` to `e`.

For the same behaviour in other applications (say your file manager), you should also change the Emacs .desktop file (for me that's `/usr/share/applications/emacs24.desktop`) to run `my_emacs`.

It might also be a good idea to change `emacs` to `my_emacsclient` via the alternatives system in Debian-based (?) distributions.

Comment: For anyone who might use my setup. It's not perfect and has some inherit flaws. For instance, if you try to `sudo -e <filename>` when no Emacs is started it will fail. Also simply invoking `e` when Emacs is already started created a new frame instead of raising the existing frame. I will try to fix this and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

`emacsclient <file>` does what you want.

If you just want to open a frame without specifying a file, then you need to use `-c`.

Comment: Not exactly. When no GUI frame exist, `emacsclient <file>` opens in a terminal frame.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `emacsclient --display "$DISPLAY" " to force creation of a GUI frame if there isn't one yet.

Comment: Mh, still doesn't work for me. It opens a terminal frame for me.

Comment: @Renke: What does `echo "DISPLAY=$DISPLAY"` tell you?

Comment: `DISPLAY=:0.0` as expected I guess.

Comment: @Renke: Duh!  You're right, I see the same problem with the "emacs --daemon".  Looks like a plain bug in server.el.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

In your emacs startup file (e.g.: ~/.emacs/init.el), ensure that you have the following lines:

```
;; start emacs server, if it's not already running:
(require 'server)
(unless (server-running-p) (server-start))
```

Then, add the following to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
function e()
{
   emacsclient "$@" -a "emacs"
}
```

To establish a baseline, make sure you exit all emacs instances and kill the emacs daemon if you currently have it running.

Then, from the command line, 'source' the ~/.bashrc file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Finally, use 'e' to edit a file:

```
e Foobar.java &
e notes.txt &
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are three states to account for:

1. Daemon not running: Start emacs and create a new frame.
2. Daemon running, but no client attached: Create a new frame attached to the daemon.
3. Client already attached to daemon: Open file in the existing frame.

This section of my ~/.zshrc is working for me:

```
emacs_start_or_attach () {
    if ! pgrep emacs &> /dev/null 2>&1
    then
        emacsclient -a '' -c $@ &
        return 0
    fi

    if pgrep emacsclient &> /dev/null 2>&1
    then emacsclient $@ &
    else emacsclient -c $@ &
    fi
}

alias emacs=emacs_start_or_attatch
export EDITOR=emacs_start_or_attatch
```

If you like, you can also start the emacs daemon at system startup and/or have emacs start the daemon on initialization (if it's not running).