# How can I close all opened frames in emacsclient?

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I have a lot of frames always open in emacs. Like I use emacsclient (daemon) and almost never restart my computer, these frames are never close. I could close one with `C-x k` but how to close all opened frames?

Comment: Do you mean buffers by any chance? Check `C-x C-b` or `list-buffers`

Comment: Also `C-x k` kills a buffer, not the associated frame.  `C-x 5 0` kills the frame (but keeps the buffer).

Comment: Why do you create so many frames in the first place, anyway?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968740/create-or-reuse-existing-emacs-gui-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work acceptably.  It will ask you if one of the buffers on the kill list has unsaved changes.

```
(defun close-all-other-buffers-and-frames ()
  "Destroy all frames except this one, kill all buffers, display `*scratch*'."
  (interactive)
  (set-buffer "*scratch*")
  (delete-other-frames)
  (let ((l (buffer-list)) b)
    (while l
      (setq b (car l)
            l (cdr l) )
      (and (buffer-file-name b)
           (kill-buffer b) ) ) ) )
```

I have a feeling the loop to kill buffers could be done more elegantly -- please suggest improvements!

Comment: I have something similar in my edits (you can visit it and look if you want to adopt something from it). I dismissed it since I did not find a way to safely detect the last opened file which I wanted to keep open. (I wanted to call it in `find-file-hook`.) I also added `buffer-modified-p` and killed only buffers that were not modified.

Answer (score 3):

Closing all frames is just quitting, is it not?

If you want to close all but one frame you can use `delete-other-frames` with the key-sequence <kbd>C-x 5 1</kbd>.

Comment: I want to avoid to close the window, then restart emacsclient and still have a lot of buffer opened. I want to quit emacsclient like I quit emacs (by closing every buffer). And when I start again emacsclient, I want a fresh emacs with no buffer opened.

Comment: If you want to quit emacs-client like emacs I do not understand why you use emacs-client at all. Then you could use emacs directly instead.

Comment: I use emacsclient because the startup is a lot quicker than emacs. I'm on a very old computer...

Comment: But that is only the case when emacs is still running. Therefore, you have at least one frame with one window which shows a buffer. Maybe, the frame is iconified.

Comment: No, I start `emacs --daemon` at the beginning of every session. I automatized this.

Comment: I don't think you can close the final frame without also quitting. If it's okay to leave one frame, then `C-x 5 1` is the ticket (perhaps with a wrapper to minimize and/or switch to the `*scratch*` buffer, or whatever).

Comment: Closing the frames will not kill their associated buffers, though. Do you want to kill all file-visiting buffers as well?